# How can i create a cascading md-select with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, material-design

I have JSON like this,

```
 $scope.analytics = {
                    'Twitter': [
                        'Following',
                        'Followers',
                        'Tweets'
                    ],
                    'Facebook': [
                        'People engaged',
                        'Likes',
                        'Clicks',
                        'Views'
                    ],
                    'LinkedIn': [
                        'Overview'

                    ]
                };
```

From the above, I need to create a cascading md-select , First md-select should have Twitter,Facebook and Linkedin.

OnChanging Twitter, it should display the Following,Followers,Tweets in the next md-select.

**HTML:**

```
<md-select ng-model="type" >
 <md-option ng-value="t" data-ng-repeat="t in analytics">{{ t }}</md-option>
 </md-select>
 <md-select ng-model="metrics" >
 <md-option ng-value="t" data-ng-repeat="t in analytics">{{ t }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

**App.JS:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.analytics = {
                    'Twitter': [
                        'Following',
                        'Followers',
                        'Tweets'
                    ],
                    'Facebook': [
                        'People engaged',
                        'Likes',
                        'Clicks',
                        'Views'
                    ],
                    'LinkedIn': [
                        'Overview'

                    ]
                }; 
});
```

Here is my code in [`Cascading md-select`](http://plnkr.co/edit/il04oft0AtL820dYoj3V?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solving this is to place a watch on the value of the first select and control the options of the second. Also remember to clear the dependent selection, when the master selection changes!

A sample implementation:

Add a `level2` variable in the scope. It will hold the options of the dependent select.

Place the watch on the first model:

```
$scope.$watch('type', function(newval, oldval) {
  if( newval ) {
    $scope.level2 = $scope.analytics[newval];
  }
  else {
    $scope.level2 = [];
  }

  // delete the dependent selection, if the master changes
  if( newval !== oldval ) {
    $scope.metrics = null;
  }
});
```

Finally the markup needs a little tweaking to display correctly:

```
<md-select ng-model="type" >
    <md-option ng-value="k" data-ng-repeat="(k,v) in analytics">{{ k }}</md-option>
</md-select>
    <md-select ng-model="metrics" >
   <md-option ng-value="t" data-ng-repeat="t in level2">{{ t }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

See a forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/rI3AsC2plZ3w82WRBjAo?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler than that. Delete the `$watch` and just change the `ng-repeat` in the `md-options` item for `metrics`

```
<md-select ng-model="type">
    <md-option ng-value="k" data-ng-repeat="(k,v) in analytics">
        {{ k }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
<md-select ng-model="metrics">
    <md-option ng-value="t" data-ng-repeat="t in analytics[type]">
        {{ t }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```